# Monitoring Stormpath Api Calls

Tags: stormpath

I have used googles youtube api in the past which offers an easy way to check how many api calls you have made in a set period e.g one month and i was wondering if stormpath provide any similar service. I can't seem to find it in my account settings?

Answer (score 0):

Stormpath doesn't currently expose this information publicly -- this is something we are working on and will release in the future =)

If you need detailed API reports, you can email us: support@stormpath.com, and we can send you your usage stats.

Comment: awesome ill be on to ye! :)